# VBA locked cells won't change color

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on something where Data should be compared. One part of the data is just for comparison (this part should be locked) and if something gets changed in the other part the color of the changed cell should change. When both sides are unlocked it works just fine. Just when I lock the one side, the color does not change anymore. Does anybody know why?

```
Set rngBereich = Intersect(Target, Range("N3:N3000,P3:P3000,T3:Z3000"))
  If Not rngBereich Is Nothing Then
    For Each rngArea In rngBereich.Areas
      For Each rngZelle In rngArea
        Dim str1 As String
        Dim str2 As String
        str1 = rngZelle.Value
        str2 = rngZelle.Offset(0, 20).Value

        If str1 <> str2 Then
          rngZelle.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Else
          rngZelle.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
      Next rngZelle
    Next rngArea
  End If
```

Comment: So `rngZelle.Offset(0, 20)` is the locked cell? I can't reproduce the error (and I even threw in a `Debug.Print rngZelle.Offset(0, 20).Locked` to confirm it is indeed locked.

Comment: Yes. `rngZelle.Offset(0, 20)` is the locked cell.

Comment: Then as mentioned, I cannot reproduce this.